# How to train a neural network for the logical OR?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

So I understand the architecture of the network. It will be two input neuron, x1 and bias. Say we give the bias a weight of 10 and the x1 a weight of -20. If x1 is 0 then sigmoid(10) = 1. If x1 is 1 then sigmoid(-10) = 0.

I tried to implement this in Matlab/Octave but I could not figure out how.

Comment: I'm not sure you're clear on how training works. I'd follow the link provided by @galloguille. You give the network the input and expected output and  set the bias and weights to very small values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all keep in mind that you need 2 inputs AND the bias, so you can have all the possible options (0,0), (0,1), (1,0) and (1,1). With only one input neuron and the bias you can't create all the possible inputs.

Then you randomly set the weights and start training by forwarding the inputs and correcting the weights using the algorithm backpropagation. To get started I recommend you to follow this tutorial http://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/, you'll learn how to train simple neural nets and how do they work.

The tutorial is in python, but it's really simple and useful to get the idea.